# Better way to absolutely position boxes to the left and right?

Tags: css, flexbox

Is there a better way to absolutely position a bunch of boxes to the left and right like this? Perhaps using flexbox?

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/zpv4jbmx/

HTML:

```
<div class="box first">
     <h1>Lipsum</h1>
</div>
<div class="box second">
     <h1>Lipsum</h1>
</div>
...
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    position: absolute;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}
.box.first, .box.third, .box.fifth {
    left: 20px;
}
.box.second, .box.fourth, .box.sixth {
    right: 20px;
}
.box.first {
    top: 20px;
}
.box.second {
    top: 120px;
}
...
```

Comment: Looks like a perfect use for floats. http://jsfiddle.net/29s3tx2v/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since we are going for "better", you could use [floating](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) and CSS [even/odd](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/) rules, like so:

#### HTML

```
<div class="box">
     <h1>Lipsum</h1>
</div>
<div class="box">
     <h1>Lipsum</h1>
</div>
<div class="box">
     <h1>Lipsum</h1>
</div>
<div class="box">
     <h1>Lipsum</h1>
</div>
<div class="box">
     <h1>Lipsum</h1>
</div>
<!-- As many as you'd like... -->
```

#### CSS

```
.box {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}
.box:nth-child(odd){
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
.box:nth-child(even){
    float: right;
    clear: both;
}
```

The result is the same, but the implementation is much more scalable.

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/9mcgvqLj/

Comment: @MarkBoulder - A note of caution - `nth-child()` does not work in IE8 (kind of like most useful CSS stuff). You'll probably need to fallback on a JS solution if you need to support < IE9 (appx [6.8% of market share](http://www.w3counter.com/trends) at the time of writing, though your site's demographic may be significantly different).